# Executing non-database actions in a transaction in Slick 3

Tags: database, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm having trouble understanding the new Slick `DBIOAction` API, which does not seem to have a lot of examples in the docs. I am using Slick 3.0.0, and I need to execute some DB actions and also some calculations with the data received from the database, but all of those actions have to be done inside a single transaction. I'm trying to do the following:

1. Execute a query to database (the `types` table).
2. Do some aggregations and filtering of the query results (this calculation can't be done on the database).
3. Execute another query, based on the calculations from step 2 (the `messages` table — due to some limitations, this query has to be in raw SQL).
4. Join data from step 2 and 3 in memory.

I want the queries from step 1 and 3 to be executed inside a transaction, as the data from their result sets has to be consistent.

I've tried to do this in a monadic join style. Here's an overly simplified version of my code, but I can't even get it to compile:

```
  val compositeAction = (for {
    rawTypes <- TableQuery[DBType].result
    (projectId, types) <- rawTypes.groupBy(_.projectId).toSeq.map(group => (group._1, group._2.slice(0, 10)))
    counts <- DBIO.sequence(types.map(aType => sql"""select count(*) from messages where type_id = ${aType.id}""".as[Int]))
  } yield (projectId, types.zip(counts))).transactionally
```

1. The first row of `for` comprehension selects the data from the `types` table.
2. The second row of `for` comprehension is supposed to do some grouping and slicing of the results, resulting in a `Seq[(Option[String], Seq[String])]`
3. The third row of `for` comprehension has to execute a set of queries for every element from the previous step, in particular, it has to execute a single SQL query for each of the values inside `Seq[String]`. So in the third row I build a sequence of `DBIOAction`s.
4. The `yield` clause `zip`s `types` from the second step and `counts` from the third step.

This construction, however, does not work and gives two compile time errors:

```
Error:(129, 16) type mismatch;
 found   : slick.dbio.DBIOAction[(Option[String], Seq[(com.centreit.proto.repiso.storage.db.models.DBType#TableElementType, Vector[Int])]),slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect]
    (which expands to)  slick.dbio.DBIOAction[(Option[String], Seq[(com.centreit.proto.repiso.storage.db.models.TypeModel, Vector[Int])]),slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
        counts <- DBIO.sequence(types.map(aType => sql"""select count(*) from messages where type_id = ${aType.id}""".as[Int]))
               ^
Error:(128, 28) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Nothing]
 required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[?,?,?]
        (projectId, types) <- rawTypes.groupBy(_.projectId).toSeq.map(group => (group._1, group._2.slice(0, 10)))
                           ^
```

I've tried to wrap the second line in a `DBIOAction` by using `DBIO.successful`, which is supposed to lift a constant value into the `DBIOAction` monad:

```
(projectId, types) <- DBIO.successful(rawTypes.groupBy(_.projectId).toSeq.map(group => (group._1, group._2.slice(0, 10))))
```

But in this code the `types` variable is inferred to be `Any`, and the code does not compile because of that.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1093#issuecomment-110252046) and see if it helps you

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Thanks, but that's not quite what I need. In this example, all of the comprehensions are updates/deletes/inserts, and they are not interconnected by their results and yield nothing (all of the left parts are `_`). In my case, one of my actions has nothing to do with database at all, and all of the actions return results that are used in other comprehensions or in the `yield`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
val compositeAction = (for {
  rawTypes <- TableQuery[DBType].result
  pair <- DBIO.sequence(rawTypes.groupBy(_.projectId).toSeq.map(group => DBIO.successful(group)))
  counts <- DBIO.sequence(pair.head._2.map(aType => sql"""select count(*) from messages where type_id = ${aType.id}""".as[Int]))
} yield (pair.head._1, pair.head._2.zip(counts))).transactionally
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I was looking for.